# Undefined variable CodeIgniter model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to understand why the `country_id` variable isn't defined in

#### Model

```
public function getCountry($country_id) {
    $this->db->select()->where('country_id', $country_id);
    $this->db->from('country');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result(); 
}
```

#### Controller

```
public function country() {
     $json = array();
     $country_info = $this->country->getCountry($country_id);

     if ($country_info) {
         $json = array(
             'country_id'        => $country_info['country_id'],
             'name'              => $country_info['name'],
             'zone'              => $this->country->getZonesByCountryId($country_id),
             'status'            => $country_info['status']
         );
     }
     echo json_encode($json);
 }
```

#### Result :

> Message: Undefined variable: country_id
>
> Filename: localisation/Countries.php
>
> Line Number: 12

Comment: Your "model" code probably isn't relevant. Did you assign to `$country_id` in the "controller" code?

Comment: Hi Ryan i posted my controller function

Comment: So... where do you expect `$country_id` to come from?

Comment: please clarify my mistake as i'm totally lost

Comment: in $country_info = $this->country->getCountry($country_id); where $country_id is defined ?

Comment: from model function

Comment: It's not global.  You must pass it into `country()` or redefine it.

Comment: This is missing the id `public function country($country_id) {`

Answer (score 1):

> Message: Undefined variable: country_id

The `$country_id` variable is not defined anywhere here.  It has no meaning because nothing has been assigned to it yet.  It just pops up out of nowhere.

```
public function country() {
     $json = array();
     $country_info = $this->country->getCountry($country_id);
     ....
```

---

You'll have to define it by assigning it a value....

```
public function country() 
{
     $json = array();
     $country_id = 3;  // <- define it here
     $country_info = $this->country->getCountry($country_id);
     ....
```

Or you can pass it in as the function's argument...

```
public function country($country_id) // <- pass it in
{
     $json = array();
     $country_info = $this->country->getCountry($country_id);
     ....
```